# How to send push notifications through cordova, using firebase with vuejs?

Tags: firebase, vuejs2

I am currently making the following example for this topic:
https://devmerz.github.io/notificaciones-push-android-apache-cordova-fcm

Which works for me when you performed a test from the page that gives the example:
 https://cordova-plugin-fcm.appspot.com/

This page works for me to send a push notification and then if it works on my mobile, if the push notification appears, the problem is that I do not know how to perform from firebase at the moment of doing an insertion to a node to execute said sending action. push notification.

Basically the insert from firebase is like this:

```
firebase
   .database()
   .ref('comunicado')
   .push(this.comunicado)
   .then(()=>{
     console.log("SEND");
     //PLACE WHERE I UNDERSTAND THE PUSH NOTICE SUBMISSION CODE SHOULD GO, WHICH I DO NOT KNOW. 
   });
```

firebase I have it implemented in a component of vue js. Thank you in advance, blessings.